# Getting error when I import 'dayjs/local/en'?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I want to add locale to my react-native-gifted-chat, because the chats do not show up one after the other, I am guessing because of time zones.

I added Locale to my gifted chat:

```
 import en from 'dayjs/locale/en'

 render() { 
    return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#000000', flex: 1}}>
            <GiftedChat
                showUserAvatar={true}
                isTyping={this.state.isTyping}
                renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
                messages={this.state.messages}
                onSend={message => this.onSend(message)}
                scrollToBottom
                locale = { en } <-----------------------------
                showAvatarForEveryMessage = {false}
                showUserAvatar= {true}
                dateFormat = 'll'
                timeFormat = 'LT'
                placeholder = "Talk to people..."
                onPressAvatar={user => this.getProfile(user)}
            />
        </View>
        
    )
```

But now I get the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n[M].replace')
```

Is this because I am using the wrong type of import, or is the existing chats the issue, and do I need to delete them for things to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it appears you need to import the locale file separately.

First you need to import daysjs:

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
```

Then you need to import the locale you want:

```js
import 'dayjs/locale/en'
```

This appears to have a global mutation side effect (bad) of making that locale available for formatting.

In your prop, pass in `locale="en"`

Then in your component (if you own it) you can use `dayjs(date).locale(this.props.locale).format()`

Daysjs doesn't look like a well designed library, because imports shouldn't have side effects like this.

Comment: I hope this fixes the issue! pushed the update to my users, you were right about having to import it like that to fix things,

Comment: Hi @kalculated! Did this solution fix it? If not, could you please point me towards your solution? Running into it myself.

Comment: @JoniVR Hey, it worked for me. You just have to pass a date that gifted chat accepts